# Are there best-practice guidelines for maintaining a repository?

Tags: github, repository

Are there best-practice guidelines for maintaining a GitHub repository? I've contributed to many open source projects and used GitHub for projects that I work on solo, but now I'm working with a team of six developers, including myself, to build a system, and I've been placed in charge of maintaining the repository. Nothing is to get merged into our main branch without my approval. As little as I know about maintaining a GitHub repository, of those within the organization (two team members are consultants) I've the most experience with the process.

But I've never maintained a GitHub repository, and while I'm doing OK, I know that there must be a body of knowledge out there of how to handle this correctly. I just haven't been able to find it.

One hurdle I've been jumping over repeatedly, for example, is merge conflicts. Usually they're minor, but not always. Is there some known system available that allows me to enforce who has the ability to edit which files at any given time, for example?

And yes, I realize this may not be the best Stack Exchange forum, but none of the others seemed more suited to the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Cloud Native Computing Foundation (CNCF)](https://www.cncf.io/) serves as the vendor-neutral home for many of the fastest-growing open source projects, including Kubernetes, Prometheus, and Envoy.

As such, it can be used as a starting point for your own project: see [`contribute.cncf.io/maintainers/github/`](https://contribute.cncf.io/maintainers/github/), which offers:

- [template](https://contribute.cncf.io/maintainers/github/templates/), to be usre you have your `README`, `LICENSE` and other important files.
- [labels](https://contribute.cncf.io/maintainers/github/issue-labels/), to better classify your issues

Add also a clear "[release and maintenance policy](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/policy/maintenance.html)", and you should be in good shape.